# Strange behaviour while interating JSON array of objects using jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

This is my sample JSON response:

```
[{"id":11137,"name":"Agra"},{"id":11138,"name":"Albizzate"}]
```

and i need to iterate each array object and print `id` and `name`:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('ajax_provinces') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {region_id: this.value},
            success: function(provinces) {},
            error: function() { alert("error"); },
            complete: function(provinces) {
                $('select#regions ~ span > img').fadeOut('slow');
                $.each(provinces, function(key, val) {
                    alert(key + ": " + val);
                });
            }
        });
```

The **problem** is i'm gettig strange results: function names, function bodies and other internal stuff from jQuery. It seems like it's **iterating through jQuery library functions**! Any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `complete` callback doesn't get passed the returned data as an argument:

> complete(jqXHR, textStatus)
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

([from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Presumably the weird key/values you're seeing are the attributes of the `jqXHR` object.

You need to handle the returned data in `success`, not `complete`. My understanding is that `complete` is generally used for actions that should happen regardless of whether the AJAX request successfully returned data (e.g. hiding a loading animation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the returned data in success, not complete. Complete is used when you need to trigger a function after AJAX call is complete.
On success you will get the data sent from server as

```
success:function(data){

/// data is JSON object. Now iterate it here 

var i;
    for(i in data){
        alert('the Id ='+data['id']+' the name '+data['name']);

      }

}
```